# Error to open Dreamweaver using wine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dreamweaver, wine

I am using ubuntu 10.04 and i want to use dreamweaver using wine, when i am opening dreamweaver.exe file using wine then, Dreamweaver window will open and it will show the error "A problem is detected with your application. Please reinstall this application to correct this problem." and close button i have to close this window.

Comment: Have you fully installed dreamweaver in wine? or are you trying to use already existing windows installation through your linux?

Comment: i m trying to used windows installed dreamweaver.

Comment: nopes, please install it in linux again, and then it would be possible to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please install your windows application in Linux altogether (using Wine).

Using a Windows installed binary has high changes of failing to work.

Also older versions of your application has greater chances to run in wine rather than newer ones.

As Wine is not driving windows Innovation, but providing a compatibility. So the latest things may not always work with Wine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, I noticed my error had a call a function not implemented on msvcp71. So overide this library (msvcp71) using winecfg and it worked for me.

Launch winecfg, go to Libraries tab, select msvcp71 under "New override for library:", click edit and choose "Native (Windows)", save and try launching dreamweaver again.